# Apache Hadoop Sqoop

Tags: apache, sqoop

I have a data like below.

```
enter code here
```

+------+-------+-----------+
| did  | dname | loc       |
+------+-------+-----------+
|  101 | AIR   | AUS       |
|  102 | AIR2  | AUS       |
|  102 | AIR3  | AUS       |
|  103 | AIR3  | AUS       |
|  104 | AIR   | USA       |
|  101 | AIR1  | USA       |
|  102 | AIR1  | USA       |
|  103 | AIR1  | AGT       |
|  104 | AIR1  | AGT       |
|  101 | AIR1  | AGT       |
|  111 | AIR1  | AGT       |
|  115 | AIR1  | USA       |
|  118 | AIR1  | UK      |
|  133 | AIR   | UK      |
|  135 | AIR   | UK      |
|  139 | AIR   | UK      |

### |  139 | AIR2  | UK      |

enter code here

I have been trying for sqoop query command like below.

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/tiger --query "select * from dept where loc='AUS' \$CONDITIONS" -m1 --target-dir /queryImport;

i am getting below error .

ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(1 = 0)' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(1 = 0)' at line 1

Can anybody please help me out with this.

Comment: use  where loc='AUS'  and \$CONDITIONS"

Comment: ya got it it was a silly mistake. Thanks for the help